# Handling the Same Class Definition From Multiple Web Services

Tags: web-services, inheritance

The situation:

We have a library project that houses much of our code for the various integrations we work on.  Many of the integrations consume web service apis, and my supervisor doesn't want 5 gazillion web service references added to the project.

What we generally do, then, is add a reference to a new project and copy the References.vb to the solution and just call the generated code.  Not terribly convenient if changes are made to the service, but it works.

Recently, I ran into a problem where we have to use 3 web services for the same integration.  2 of these contain the same class definitions, however, they're in different namespaces because they belong to different services.  This became a problem for me because one of the services searches a user based on user ID, and the other pulls back blocks of users.  Both return an object, or list of, that is exactly the same semantically.  And I need to process the data the same, whether it came from one service or the other.

My solution, was to strip out the duplicated classes in the service and replace them with classes inherited from common base classes.  This allowed me to work with both objects as if they were the same, however, it required modifying the generated web service proxy.  Therefore this change will need to be made every time I need to regenerate the proxy.

I'm curious what you all might think a better solution to this would be.

Comment: Wait, is your manager worried about having multiple ASMX files per project or does he/she actually care how many public methods are added to the service?

Comment: Actually, this is regarding consuming web services, not creating them.  I've changed the wording in the question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wsdl.exe` using the `/sharetypes` switch allows the same types to be used across multiple service definitions, provided the wire signatures are not correct.  I was unable to use it in my situation, though, because the various wsdl contracts were carelessly namespaced.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to regret playing games with copying Reference.vb and editing generated files.

Switch to WCF and you'll be able to tell it you want to reuse the types, instead of having multiple types that are more or less the same.

BTW, they would be "less" the same if not all of the web references are updated at the same time after a server change.

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to build an abstraction layer over top of the web service pre-generated proxies, such that when you make to the calls to the abstraction layer you can always use the same objects, as they are squeezed into (and out of) the web service proxies in the abstraction layer.  This would also allow for unit testing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you really should be looking at WCF for 3.5+, but for .NET 2.0 look at something like WSCF (Web Services Contract First), which defines the contracts in XML and generates a set of libraries reusable across services. E.g You define a MyComany.WS.Common namespace and use that namespace in multiple projects. The code generation then builds a shared library of types which get used across all the web-services. We use this extensively in our .NET 2 solutions and it's great. We had to do some additional work around the code generation to get it to fit into our build process, but once that was done we never looked back.

We're migrating to .NET 3.5 over time, so the WSCF will become obsolete

Heres the link to the [thinktecture](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/wscf) site for WSCF.